# Spring + Hibernate - Persisting/Committing data doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm one on one with the guides code under the section "A post this long must mean a lot of code and configuration".

http://blog.springsource.com/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring/

The problem is, that only select-like queries work. When i try to persist a bean/entity the query just doesn't happen (i have show sql option set on for Hibernate). I know this is propably something related to springs configuration, but i have no experience on what to look for.

Spring configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" />

<bean id="productDaoImpl" class="product.ProductDaoImpl"/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory"
        ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

```
Dao:

    @Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this. entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    // works
    public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Product p where p.category = :category")
            .setParameter("category", category).getResultList();
    }

   // Doesn't even get queried for
   public void persistWhatever(Product product) { entityManger.persist(product); }
}
```

Comment: You can only persist while inside a transaction. Have you configured the transaction manager correctly?

Comment: something wrong with transaction?

Comment: I have the same configuration as the given link. It does select queries so i assume Spring is managing my transactions ?

Comment: you have no tx declared on 'persistWhatever'. you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you don't have `@Transactional` on your service methods (those calling the DAO). Usually service methods are the place to put `@Transactional` (some people put it on DAO methods, but that's unnecessarily granular)

Comment: Didn't have Transactional and from the error messages generated after setting the annotations it seems i  didn't have the correct configuration aswell.